# Announcing a Pro Tempore election for 2021

Tags: discussion, election

**Summary**: Veganism & Vegetarianism Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [a special election](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/election/1) on **July 26** to bring in two more moderators.

For full details of the process, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections). The timeline:

- Starting on July 26, users can [nominate themselves](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/election/1). Users can also ask questions on meta for potential moderators to answer. (Use the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [election](/questions/tagged/election) tags.)
- On August 2, if there are three or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, I'll extend the nomination period for a week. If, at the end of that extension period there are still less than three candidates, I'll simply appoint the candidates. (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year), but I doubt that will come up.)
- If there is an election, I'll announce the results on meta on August 10 (or August 17, if we need to extend the nomination period).

(Note for current moderators: there's no need to nominate yourself even though you'll likely get an email saying you should. The system assumes the first election is a graduation election, which would mean moderators would need to be re-elected. This isn't that sort of election.)

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.

Comment: "The system assumes the first election is a graduation election, which would mean moderators would need to be re-elected. This isn't that sort of election." Now you got me curious. Does this mean the system won't send out the obligatory e-mail during a next graduation election while it should?

Comment: I... actually don't know, @Mast :P Lemme try to figure that out.

Comment: Glad to be of service.

Comment: Good luck to anyone planning on running! :)

Comment: Looks like it only gets sent on the very first election indeed, @Mast — I'm putting in a request to kill that email altogether, and we'll ensure pro-tems are aware of what they need (or don't need) to do whenever there are elections. We'll adjust this template once that's completed.